# Properties of shapes defined by locus of points with a function of distances

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, analytic-geometry

Different shapes such as hyperbola and ellipse can be defined as a locus of points. For example, if we denote distance to points $P_1$ and $P_2$ from any arbitrary point as $d_1(x,y)$ and $d_2(x,y)$. The locus of points for which
$$d_1+d_2=\text{const}$$
will be an ellipse.

> Are the properties of 2-dimensional shapes defined by the locus of points which is only a function of distances from several other points, well-studied? Does anyone know useful references on this subject?
>
> More precisely, let by $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_n$ be several fixed points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Denote the distances of an arbitrary point $C=(x,y)$ from these fixed points by $d_1(x,y),d_2(x,y),\ldots, d_n(x,y)$. I'm interested in studying the properties of the curves defined as
> $$ f(d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_n) = \text{const}.$$

As suggested by user @Blue, for the particular case where $f$ computes the sum of the distances, the resulting curve for k points is called a [k-ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ellipse).

Comment: You may be interested in [Cayley ovals](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d/cayleyovale/cayleyovale.shtml), related to [Cassini ovals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval).

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Thank you for your comment. The curves were very interesting.